# How to avoid updating EntityModel.Context for existing Stored Procedure?

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework, stored-procedures

I am developing a windows application. I have an Entity Model of Model type Generate from database. I have imported some Stored Procedures at first and for one SP i have changed the context replacing datatype from bool to int. Now when i try to update the model (adding SP) the context of the changed SP is back to its default type i.e bool resulting in an error (function has invalid arguments).

This is the Context.cs of the model. Here when i change type from bool to int, application is working fine but when i update the model the type is back to bool and its throwing error. How to avoid this?

```
public virtual ObjectResult<Web_get_obj_details_Result> Web_get_obj_details(Nullable<byte> hcode, Nullable<byte> vcode, Nullable<byte> yearcode, Nullable<short> tranno)
        {
            var hcodeParameter = hcode.HasValue ?
                new ObjectParameter("hcode", hcode) :
                new ObjectParameter("hcode", typeof(byte));

            var vcodeParameter = vcode.HasValue ?
                new ObjectParameter("vcode", vcode) :
                new ObjectParameter("vcode", typeof(byte));

            var yearcodeParameter = yearcode.HasValue ?
                new ObjectParameter("yearcode", yearcode) :
                new ObjectParameter("yearcode", typeof(byte));

            var trannoParameter = tranno.HasValue ?
                new ObjectParameter("tranno", tranno) :
                new ObjectParameter("tranno", typeof(short));

            return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction<Web_get_obj_details_Result>("Web_get_obj_details", hcodeParameter, vcodeParameter, yearcodeParameter, trannoParameter);
        }
```

How i am accessing SP :

```
IList<Web_get_obj_details_Result> ObjWeb_get_obj_details_Result = EntityObj.Web_get_obj_details(HobliCode, VillageCode, YearCode,TranNo).ToList<Web_get_obj_details_Result>();
```

Here HobliCode, VillageCode,YearCode,TranNo are of type int.

FYI: This is my SP

```
ALTER PROCEDURE  [dbo].[Web_get_obj_details]
@hcode as tinyint , @vcode as tinyint , @yearcode as tinyint , @tranno as smallint
as
declare @dcode as integer , @tcode as integer 
begin tran
    select @dcode = dist_code , @tcode  = taluk_code from mst_config 
    select convert(varchar(10),notice_sdate,103) as notice_sdate ,convert(varchar(10),obj_date,103) as obj_date,objector_name,obj_details from tr_objection
    where dist_code= @dcode and taluk_code = @tcode and  hobli_code = @hcode  and village_code = @vcode and tran_no =@tranno and year_code=@yearcode 
commit tran
```

I do not want to change the context of that SP every time i update the model. Any solution?? And why the model is fetching the type as bool even though the type is int?

Comment: You mean `bool` or `byte`?

Comment: @sefe sorry.. It is byte..

Answer (score 1):

Your stored procedure uses `tinyint` and `smallint` as parameter types. EF reflects that in the accessor method of your stored procedure and generates the method with the respective types `byte` and `short` (aka `Byte` and `Int16`) wrapped in `Nullable<T>`.

The golden rule in EF database first is: do not modify the generated code. It will be overwritten on the next update.

You have two options to resolve your problem:

1. Change your stored procedure to use `int` types for your parameters and update your model from the database. The access method will be using `int` (aka `Int32`) then.
2. Create a wrapper method in your custom extensions to the context. You can make the auto-generated method private (through the designer - remember to never modify auto-generated code) to prevent direct access.

This would look like this:

```
public ObjectResult<Web_get_obj_details_Result> Web_get_obj_details(int hcode, int vcode, int yearcode, int tranno)
{
    return Web_get_obj_details((byte)hcode, (byte)vcode, (byte)yearcode, (short)tranno);
}
```

Comment: I quite did not understand the 2nd point. You are telling me to create a  method in the context class? Would not that be ambiguous ? Even if i change the method to private(you are saying not to) it will be public on the next update right?

Comment: It wouldn't be ambiguous, it's a normal overload. And you change it to private _in the visual designer_. Then it will not oberwritten. You can't touch the auto generated code. You can edit in the visual designer and you can edit your own partial context class.